# Как Взять данные из базы данных и сохранить их в переменных без обновления страницы после отправления формы?

Tags: php, html, ajax

Всем привет!

У меня есть две кнопки: Эксперт и начинающий

```
<form action="assets/php/difficultchoice.php" method="GET">
                  <button data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary diffbtn btn-block reserve-button" id="beginnerDif" name="Beginner" type="submit" >Beginner</button> 
                  <button data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary btn-block reserve-button" id="expertDif" type="submit" name="Expert" >Expert</button> </form> </div>
```

При нажатии например на кнопку эксперт, из базы данных должны браться подсказки для  экспертов и сохраняться в переменные чтобы в дальнейшем я смог вывести их при нажатии на кнопку подсказки. У эксперта и начинающего разные подсказки.

При нажитие на кнопку активируется пхп код:

```
if (isset($_GET['Expert'])) {
       include('connect.php');
       $tbName = 'hint';

       $sql_select = "SELECT * from tbName WHERE Level = 'Expert'";

       if ($stmt_select = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql_select)) {
           $execute_select = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt_select);
           if ($execute_select == FALSE) {
               echo mysqli_error($con);
           }
           mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt_select, $hintId, $level, $description, $hintText);
           mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt_select);
           if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt_select) == 0) {
               echo 'oopsie';
           } else {
              while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt_select)) {
                 if ($description = "osint") {
                   echo $hintText;

                 }else{
                    echo "nope";
                 }

             }




           }


    }

    }elseif (isset($_GET['Beginner'])) {
      include('connect.php');
    }


    else{
      echo "whoopsie daisy";
    }
```

но после нажатия на кнопку страница обновляется. Я знаю что это можно избежать при помощи AJAX, но никак не могу понять как это сделать.

Очень прошу помощи и заранее благодарю

Comment: ну вы хотя бы скриптик на js накидайте. По ajax в интернете полно документации

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте JS (c библиотекой jQuery).

```js
$('#beginnerDif').click(function() {

  $.get('assets/php/difficultchoice.php?beginnerDif').then(function(response) {
    document.write(response)
  });

  return false; // избегаем перезагрузки старницы
});
```